# How i can integrate fingerprint scanning device javascript

Tags: php, javascript, fingerprint

I like to develop software with PHP JavaScript that read fingerprint scanner

- can JavaScript read and send via ajax
  -

Comment: See [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13760464/1615483) why it's not the best idea in the world. If you can access the scanner like a camera, you can go through `navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia`, otherwise I'm not sure any current native _JavaScript_ API would work, so you'd have to load an applet/object/something else.

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility is to take advantage of WebSockets. Set up a WebSocket server in a language that has access to the finger print scanner, and establish a connection to the WebSocket server from JavaScript. You can pass raw data through the socket to the device using this, however if you are using the fingerprints for security purposes, it is probably not a good idea. (my point being that anyone could reverse engineer the driver to send fake finger data)

Answer (score 0):

Javascript does not have access to a finger print scanner.  Therefore, a plain browser page will not be able to trigger the fingerprint scanner or get data from it.  You would probably need a browser plug-in/add-on or native app in order to be able get access to that type of data.

Comment: would you like to give an example of "native app" or browser plugin?

Comment: @Potheek - a native app is an app like Photoshop (an executable application that you download and install on your computer).  A browser plug-in/add-on/extension is like something you would find here: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/category/popular?hl=en-US.

Comment: thanks but I do know the definition. Sorry, I think I could not phrase it correctly. I was actually asking for an example regarding this situation. Is there any alternative to ActiveX Plugin (like the facebook option to take photo direct from the webcam)? If not, is there any ActiveX Plugin exists for fingerprint scanner? I hope I am able to make it clear.

Comment: @Potheek - I don't know specific examples for a finger print scanner - you'd have to do some research.  I don't even know if there's a standard for finger print scanner interfaces - a solution may be specific to the particular finger print scanner hardware.